# Export summary.PCA (package FactoMineR) into a table, with R-cran

Tags: r

I am currently doing a PCA of some data with 35rows and 21 columńs by using the package FactoMineR of R. I'm doing this for my bachelor thesis and I'm studying forestry, so "I have no clue what I'm doing" :).

It works somehow and the interpretation is another chapter, but my Professors, unfortunately also have no clue what they are doing in this statistics kind of thing, so they expect the results in nice little word-sheets, with the data nicely arranged into tables.

The text-output is printed by me with the following methods:

```
capture.output(mydata)
summary.PCA(mydata)
summary(mydata)
```

summary.PCA is a tool directly from the package FactoMineR and I use it because capture.output keeps giving me errors when I try and capture PCA("whatever") with it.

But this output is impossible to import into a table unless I do i all by hand, which I cannot accept as a solution (I very much hope so).

Output like the following.. I don't see a way to put this into a table:

```
Call:
PCA(mydata) 


Eigenvalues
                   Dim.1   Dim.2   Dim.3   Dim.4   Dim.5   Dim.6   Dim.7   Dim.8   Dim.9  Dim.10  Dim.11  Dim.12  Dim.13  Dim.14  Dim.15  Dim.16  Dim.17  Dim.18  Dim.19  Dim.20  Dim.21 
Variance               8.539   2.937   1.896   1.644   1.576   1.071   0.738   0.695   0.652   0.463   0.261   0.184   0.136   0.108   0.049   0.021   0.019   0.010   0.000   0.000   0.000 
% of var.             40.662  13.984   9.027   7.830   7.505   5.100   3.517   3.311   3.106   2.203   1.242   0.878   0.650   0.513   0.233   0.102   0.093   0.046   0.000   0.000   0.000 
Cumulative % of var.  40.662  54.645  63.672  71.502  79.007  84.107  87.624  90.934  94.041  96.244  97.486  98.363  99.013  99.526  99.759  99.862  99.954 100.000 100.000 100.000 100.000
```

So is there a way to do this? Do I have to transform the data before I can print it into a table?

I hope very much I have expressed myself clearly!

All the best!

Lukas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The summary.PCA function writes all the tables data are available in the outputs.
So you can do:

res <- PCA(mydata)

res$eig    ### and you will have the table with the eigenvalues in an object

res$ind$coord   ## and you will have the coordinate of the individuals in an object

write.infile(res,file="OutputFile.csv")   ## and all the outputs will be written in a csv file

Hope it helps,
Francois